# PHP regex with wildcards between 3 strings

Tags: php, regex

The strings are:

```
<aaa>
bbb
>
```

The wildcards, that should include line breaks, should go between string 1 and 2, and 2 and 3

With my total misunderstanding of regular expressions, I wrote this:

```
$end = preg_replace('/^<aaa>(\s\S)*bbb(\s\S)*>$/','',$start);
```

Can anyone help me make this work? Thanks!

so as an example my starting string would be like:

```
$start = "<aaa><b>QqRr</b>

<zzz>dddbbb

</zzz>Test1234</aaa>";
```

and end would look like

```
$end = "Test1234</aaa>";
```

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: I've edited the question to give an example.

Comment: Use this site - https://regex101.com/ - to create a regular expression and apply it to your requirements.

Comment: You're using regex to parse html/xml and you really shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using strip_tags(); to parse the data. With it you can also add allowed tags, so any 
 can eventually be replaced with \r\n to keep the

Answer (score 0):

You build the regex too complicated.

Instead drop everything *but* what's coming after the last "`>`":

```
/^.*>([^>]*)$/s
    ^
    1
```

The s modifier is that . matches line-separators as well.

In code:

```
$end = preg_replace('/^.*>([^>]*)$/s','\1', $start);
```

You can then further on extend to match the two other patterns if those are important to you:

```
/^<aaa>.*bbb.*>([^>]*)$/s
  ^^^^^  ^^^  ^
    3     2   1
```

Comment: I've updated the example and the regex that I feel should work that still isn't working to more accurately reflect my situation. Thanks for your input!

Comment: if I put your last extended code into regex101.com it gives me an unescaped delimiter error.

Comment: nevermind i copied it wrong. After I put it into my php page it still isnt working for some reason. I guess I'll go back to more troubleshooting on my end and see if I'm just missing something.